# How add condition "IF NOT EXISTS" to AddIndexConcurrently in Django Migrations?

Tags: python, django, indexing, django-migrations

I want to add index on model field concurrently using **AddIndexConcurrently**. How can I add condition **"IF NOT EXISTS"**?

- Now my query run like `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "chat_chatmessage_type_idx" ON "chats_chatmessage" ("type");`
- But I need to transform it to `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS "chat_chatmessage_type_idx" ON "chats_chatmessage" ("type");`

```
database_operations=[
                AddIndexConcurrently(
                    model_name='chatmessage',
                    index=models.Index(
                        fields=["type"],
                        name="chat_chatmessage_type_idx",
                        condition=??something like this - Q("IF NOT EXISTS")??
                    )
                )]
```

I'm using django 3.1.7 and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible while looking at [the schema used by Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py#L23).

You could use [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) to run `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS "chat_chatmessage_type_idx" ON "chats_chatmessage" ("type");` but that's a quite hacky solution.